# What is a better way to encode a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm implementing a Huffman compression algorithm. I have a binary tree that contains every character of my source, and I need to be able to encode a given character by it's position in the tree. For example:

```
  /\            If we use this tree, and say that a 0 represents the left branch,
 a  |           and a 1 represents the right branch, our encoded characters would
   / \          be:
  |   b              a = 0    b = 11
 / \                 c = 100  d = 101
c   d
```

The current method I use to encode characters as specified is something like this:

```
treeHas(char, tree){
     if(tree = Leaf) return char == tree.value
     else return treeHas(char, tree.left) || treeHas(char, tree.right)
}

encodeChar(char, tree){
     if(treeHas(tree.left)) return concat("0", encodeChar(char, tree.left))
     if(treeHas(tree.right)) return concat("1", encodeChar(char, tree.right))
     error
}
```

It works, but it seems very inefficient. Both `treeHas` and `encodeChar` walk the tree recursively. Is there more efficient algorithm? Perhaps one that only walks the tree once?

Comment: Sure, you can traverse the tree once and build an encoding table with a bit pattern and a length for each symbol. You then use this table to actually encode the input.

Comment: Good idea. This is likely what I'll go with.

Comment: Asking for software reviews is off topic here. Go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. Delete this question first. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could collect all encodings in one go; in JavaScript:

```js
function encode(tree, path="") {
    if (!tree.left && !tree.right) return [[tree.value, path]];
    let result = [];
    if (tree.left ) result = result.concat(encode(tree.left , path + "0"));
    if (tree.right) result = result.concat(encode(tree.right, path + "1"));
    return result;
}

// Demo
let tree = {
    left: { value: "a" },
    right: {
        left: {
            left: { value: "c" },
            right: { value: "d" }
        },
        right: { value: "b" }
    }
};
let result = encode(tree);
console.log(result);
```